# How to display multiple pushpins on bing map

Tags: android, geolocation, bing-maps

i want to display multiple pushpins using latitude and longitudes in bing map, is there any example to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, head over to the [Bing Maps V7 Interactive SDK](http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#Pushpins5), they have a whole section regarding the usage of Pushpins, including one example that adds 50 of them on the map using random latitude and longitude coordinates.